# display the search result from a particular path on top than other

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have content structure as below
content
----- mysite
-------pathv1
------pathv2
My intention to display the result from the search path V1 before V2. The full-text search is returning randomly. I tried to use the orderby = path but it is not working.
Below is my query.

```
type=cq:Page
path=/content/mysite
fulltext=This is a test copy
p.limit = -1
1_orderby=path
2_orderby=@jcr:content/jcr:lastModified
orderby.sort=desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@jcr:path` instead of `path`:

```
type=cq:Page
path=/content/mysite
fulltext=This is a test copy
p.limit = -1
1_orderby=@jcr:path
2_orderby=@jcr:content/jcr:lastModified
1_orderby.sort=desc
2_orderby.sort=desc
```